# Pandas: get dummies and keep other column as values

Tags: pandas, pivot, one-hot-encoding

I have a dataframe like this:

| Sequence | Message |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | B |
| 3 | C |
| 4 | D |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | C |
| 3 | D |
| 4 | E |
| 5 | F |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | C |
| 3 | D |

And I'm trying to pivot it to have table with maximum `Sequence` length as columns and corresponding possible `Message` as values.

| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | C | D |  |  |  |
| A | C | D | E | F |  |  |
| A | C | D |  |  |  |  |

I'm trying to use pd.get_dummies() for `Sequence` , but can't figure out how to keep `Message` values.

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) with `df['Sequence'].diff().le(0).cumsum()` as index (new row when the Sequence restarts to an earlier number):

```
(df.assign(index=df['Sequence'].diff().le(0).cumsum())
   .pivot(index='index', columns='Sequence', values='Message')
   .rename_axis(index=None, columns=None) # optional
)
```

Output:

```
   1  2  3    4    5
0  A  B  C    D  NaN
1  A  C  D    E    F
2  A  C  D  NaN  NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution:

```
(df.groupby(df['Sequence'].where(df['Sequence'] == 1, 0).cumsum())
 .apply(lambda x: x.set_index('Sequence').T)
 .reset_index(drop=True).rename_axis(None, axis=1))
```

Output:

```
   1  2  3    4    5
0  A  B  C    D  NaN
1  A  C  D    E    F
2  A  C  D  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: Something wrong, first sequence should be `A B C D`, but here `A B C D F`

Comment: I guess I misinterpreted your question. I will fix that later on.

Comment: My new solution fixes that, @Alex_Y. Please, see it.